# granted read access to file to everyone, yet SQL Server cannot bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, windows, file-permissions, bulkinsert

Using Windows 10, SQL Server 2016.
My machine name is FR-PC4335.
Granted acces to file

\\FR-PC4335\Users\aubertl\Documents\csv\Exemple fichier cout de production.csv

to "everyone".
Logged on to the server using remote desktop and was able to access that UNC path using file explorer.
Yet, on a BULK INSERT attempt, SQL Server returns

Msg 4861 Level 16: access denied.

Do I need to give specific access to SQL Server, on top of everyone ?

Using Windows Authentication for the SQL Server connection.

```
BULK INSERT #temptable
FROM '\\FR-PC4335\Users\aubertl\Documents\csv\Exemple fichier cout de production.csv'
WITH
(firstrow=2,fieldterminator=',',rowterminator='\n');
```

Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Bulk load impossible because file "\\FR-PC4335\Users\aubertl\Documents\csv\Exemple fichier cout de production.csv" cannot be opened. os error code 5(access denied.).

Looks like I have bulkadmin permission:

```
SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('bulkadmin') AS bulkadmin;
```

[image]

The BULK INSERT query runs successfully if launched directly on the server, but it fails if run from client SSMS. I wonder why.

Comment: What account to di you think it's using? I believe it uses the SQL Server service account. If it's the default (LOCAL SYSTEM), then this explicitly does _not_ have network access. Change the SQL Server service account.

Comment: Granting `EVERYONE` access to a user's documents folder is a ***really*** bad idea too. Put it in a share that everyone has access to, or that specific users including the SQL Server Service Account (that needs to be a **domain** account).

Comment: @NickMcDermaid, I am using Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server, running on a remote server.

Comment: So did you change the SQL Server service account? It isn't using your account to access the file.

Comment: @NickMcMermaid, don't think I have the credentials to do that. Don't have the hand on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploaded the file to the server. Ran:

```
BULK INSERT #temptable
--FROM '\\FR-COUVSQL200\csv\Exemple_fichier_cout_de_production.csv'
FROM 'C:\csv\Exemple_fichier_cout_de_production.csv'    
WITH
(firstrow=2,fieldterminator=';',rowterminator='\n')
;
```

From my SSMS on the client. And it worked. The file had previously been uploaded to `C:\csv` on the server. Oddly, using UNC to the same path fails.

Answer (score -1):

You give a path that is relative to your PC and for a specific user, but will not be suitable for a server for privacy reasons despites the file rights you give. You need to have a not only a shared folder, but a stict path which is not in the USER one. ....

Try to put your file into a direct folder on a real disk (C for instance).

If you are french you can also ask this questions in the developpez.com french forums in french....

Comment: Given that the path is a UNC path and there is no indication that the server can not reach the computer this should not be the reason.

Comment: Tried placing the file directly under C: (UNC=\\FR-PC4335\csv\....csv), granted everyone access to  the directory C:\csv. In the end, same punishment :(